# Stopping a flutter scale animation

Tags: flutter, animation, scale

could someone help with a scale animation that am attempting to perform.
What I want to achieve is a scale animation of an image, I have managed to scale animate it but I want it stop one the image is fully scaled.
If I use the stop method on the animation controller the image does not display, how can I stop the animation after the image has fully scaled??

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: todo
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));
    animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeIn);

    //controller.repeat(reverse: false); // with this line of code the image scales up and down
    controller.stop(canceled: true); //This line of code is failing to stop the animation
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
      // appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Acsz Show'), centerTitle: true),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          //Remove this constant
          const Text('Welcome',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 55,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          // SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          const Text('To',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 35,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          ScaleTransition(
              scale: animation,
              child:
                  SizedBox(child: Image.asset('images/logo.png', height: 200))),
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          // Image.network('https://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/popeye_logo.png')
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                  minimumSize: const Size(300, 40)),
              child: const Text('Show'))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The solution is to just add the forward method to the controller object as below:

```
controller.foward();
```

The forward method Starts running this animation forwards (towards the end), so the animation stops when it reaches the end.